# Php 64bit integer hash

Tags: php

Is there a one way hashing algorithm, that can give an integer hash of 64 bits?
Tried converting md5 hex into integer(storing large int using gmp library in PHP), but I'll lose precision. Same with SHA1.

Is there an existing algorithm (in php or otherwise), that will give a int or a hex which I can convert to an integer(max 64 bits).

Comment: I hope you're not doing anything secure with it...

Comment: Not really. Mostly just to prevent people from knowing the original data

Answer (score 3):

There're [plenty of algorithms](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php), to convert them to an integer you can make use of the [`gmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extension:

```
$base16 = hash('md5', 'hello world');
$base10 = gmp_strval(gmp_init(strtoupper($base16), 16), 10);
```

Where `$base16` is the hexadecimal digest returned by the hash function.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `print_r(hash_algos());` to see a list of all available PHP hash algorithms, and take your pick for one that suits your needs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => md2
    [1] => md4
    [2] => md5
    [3] => sha1
    [4] => sha224
    [5] => sha256
    [6] => sha384
    [7] => sha512
    [8] => ripemd128
    [9] => ripemd160
    [10] => ripemd256
    [11] => ripemd320
    [12] => whirlpool
    [13] => tiger128,3
    [14] => tiger160,3
    [15] => tiger192,3
    [16] => tiger128,4
    [17] => tiger160,4
    [18] => tiger192,4
    [19] => snefru
    [20] => snefru256
    [21] => gost
    [22] => adler32
    [23] => crc32
    [24] => crc32b
    [25] => salsa10
    [26] => salsa20
    [27] => haval128,3
    [28] => haval160,3
    [29] => haval192,3
    [30] => haval224,3
    [31] => haval256,3
    [32] => haval128,4
    [33] => haval160,4
    [34] => haval192,4
    [35] => haval224,4
    [36] => haval256,4
    [37] => haval128,5
    [38] => haval160,5
    [39] => haval192,5
    [40] => haval224,5
    [41] => haval256,5
)
```